# Sending a chat message to a microsoft Teams channel using Microsoft Graph API C#

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

My goal is simple. 
I want to send an automated chat message in to a MS Teams channel using the graph API.

This seems to be beta feature of the graph API and is only avalible in the Microsoft.Graph.Beta.

I have read the docs and have been trying to follow this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages, I have all the permissions set correct in my azure portal. I keep getting 'Unknown Error' I have tried:

```
var graphServiceClient = MicrosoftGraphService.GetGraphServiceClient();

            var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
            {
                Subject = null,

                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                    Content = messageText
                }

            };

            var response = await graphServiceClient.Teams["77f9c17f-54ca-4275-82d4-fff7esdacda1"].Channels["2007765c-8185-4cc7-8064-fb1b10f27e6b"].Messages.Request()
               .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

I have also tried to to see if I can get anything from teams:

```
var teams = await graphServiceClient.Teams["77f9c17f-54ca-4275-2sed4-ffsde59acda1"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Again all I get is Unknown error, I have used GRAPH API before to do things like get users in an organisation, so I know the genreal set up is correct.

Has anyone on the Internet somewhere in the world got this to work?! becuase its driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here :

Everything is ok with users or groups, but I can't get anything from Teams (unknownError)

All IDs are correct and checked

Here are the authorizations I have set for the app :

- Read all users' teamwork activity feed
- Read all groups
- Send a teamwork activity to any user
- Get a list of all teams

Here is my code (based on [microsoft daemon app scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview))

The access token is ok

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta",
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    }));

var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
{
    Subject = "Message de test",
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = "Contenu de test"
    }
};

await graphClient.Teams["218a4b1d-84d5-48a2-97a0-023e4e4c3e85"].Channels["19:adbf8ddf37a049aa9f63a0f8ee0e8054@thread.tacv2"].Messages
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

And the result :

```
Token acquired
Code: UnknownError
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: e2e433d8-cedd-4401-b5b2-6f34cf5611cf
    date: 2020-03-30T12:14:15
ClientRequestId: e2e433d8-cedd-4401-b5b2-6f34cf5611cf
```

Edit(2020-04-01) :

No solution at the time being : there are answers to comments at the bottom of the page ["Create chatMessage in a channel" in ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) (feedback section)

It seems that applications cannot be granted the permission to send chatMessages up to now.

> RamjotSingh commented on Jun 11, 2019 Contributor
>
> @pythonpsycho1337 - As the permission table above notes, Application
>   only context is not supported on this API at the moment.

---

> RamjotSingh commented on Dec 16, 2019 Contributor
>
> Supporting application permissions is something we plan to do but we do not have a date yet.

---

> RamjotSingh commented a day ago Contributor
>
> We will share on Microsoft Graph Blog once we have application
>   permissions for this API. Since the original question for this issue
>   was answered. Closing it.

Comment: In the end I discovered that every teams channel has an email address. So I just send an email to that address instead. For me that was what I needed, maybe you could do the same.