# Deployed azure function get bad request from GraphApi Rest call but the action is a success

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I developed an azure function inside Visual Studio, which access some graph api endpoints and writes into azure storage some information. When i tested the function on my pc, everything works perfect.

- When i deployed the function into azure, everything works but not the azure storage part. What am I doing wrong?
- The variables are in DEV-OPS pipeline and I check in azure portal and there are present as well.

Edit 1: As I started to try to log information I was able to see that my functions is just running the first call and not even finishing it. I used before and after each call.

```
log.Info()
```

This is the GraphAPI Call, I know it is in preview but this shouldn't be a problem as this code is running fine on my pc in visual studio.

```
public static async Task<ChatMessage> CreateNewMessageThread(Employee employee)
        {
            var chatMessage = ChatThreadMainMessage(employee);

            var result = await GraphServiceClient
                .Teams[ApplicationConfigurationFields.TeamsId]
                .Channels[ApplicationConfigurationFields.ChannelId]
                .Messages
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(chatMessage);

            return result;
        }
```

Edit 2: I am getting a BadRequest from the call which throws an exception. although i am getting a bad request, the message is still created... Even if I find the problem I would like to understand why is that happening.

This is the stack trace, don't know if it will help someone.

```
Status Code: BadRequest
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: BadRequest
Message: Bad Request
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: 220c1508-5bbd-xxxxx-xxxxx
    date: 2020-04-27T16:02:01
ClientRequestId: 220c1508-5bbd-xxxxxx-xxxxx

   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__31`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MsTeamsNotifications.MsTeamsNotifications.<CreateNewMessageThread>d__19.MoveNext()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try logging the variable values in the azure function if they are getting picked up correctly from the configuration?

Comment: Hey @Kamesh, thanks for  the idea. I updated the post with Edit1.

Comment: You mean your function is stuck in the graph api call itself? If so, put a try catch in that fn code and log the exception. It happened to me sometimes that azure fn did not fail but got stuck due to exceptions. So try it if you can get the detail on any error

Comment: That stack trace looks incomplete. Can you add the full stack trace?

Comment: I added the full stack trace which was just 5 more lines with the info i provided before. I don't know if the graph send back sensitive information with those GUID's but for safety I censored them. If those GUID's can be used to see more information, please let me know how. @Kamesh

Comment: I think you are using it the wrong way. You should create an instance of GraphServiceClient with proper authentication and then use it to add messages. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561348/sending-a-chat-message-to-a-microsoft-teams-channel-using-microsoft-graph-api-c

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp

Comment: I'm not getting error for authorization problems. And again on my PC everything works perfect.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: If i remember correctly, it was a stupid mistake on my part. Double check your variables used. It seems that the GraphAPI can work with different ID's even though they shouldn't. Hope this can help a bit! @FilthySlider